# Dropbox-like solution for two power users with dynamic IPs that doesn't use the cloud?

Tags: files, file-sharing

A friend and I share a lot of files between ourselves. We would like a way that makes it easy for us to send files to one another without the need for the other to be there to accept the transfer. i.e. I can upload files to a folder on his computer whenever I'd like, and he can do the same for me.

Here are our constraints:

- We are both running Ubuntu 18.04
- We both have dynamic IP addresses
- We are both on residential cable-based internet and behind consumer-grade routers.

Here are our goals:

- The sender can initiate and complete the transaction alone -- the receiver does not need to be at their computer.
- We want to avoid cloud-based solutions like Dropbox.
- We strongly prefer libre gnu/gpl based software. ([Resilio Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resilio_Sync) may be our solution, but I'd rather avoid proprietary software if possible.)
- The solution is somewhat robust -- i.e. it won't break every month due to normal things like IP changes, etc.

Is there a solution that fits our needs?

Comment: Use any vpn solution (e.g. tor hidden network service), set up samba servers, then mount each other.

Comment: [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) is perfect for this.

Comment: @jasonwryan I would like to upvote Syncthing as the right tool for the job. Please post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would get a dyndns or no-ip account one for each of you. Run the updater client on each of your systems. Then use the staic adresses that you create to sshfs mount a drive or folder on eachothers systems.

```
 sshfs username@someinetaddress.com:/path/to/mount/remote /where/to/mount/local
```

Then you could just use it like a local folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) up to now for similar robust file-sharing (minus a separate server). However, lately I have been using [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/), which has been [Docker-ized](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/) as well so you can be up and running lickity-split.  It works quite well and even has some plugins which can be useful beyond file-sharing.

Couple this with any of the myriad Dynamic DNS services and you've got file-sharing on-the-go. By the way, we used something similar to this for the Heard Island Expedition and it worked even via our Inmarsat connection.

Lately I have been having great results with [SyncThing](https://syncthing.net/), which can be set up to work securely and without user intervention.  I use it to sync very large video files between two editing workstations.